# Rename object properties without the mediation of a new variable

Tags: javascript

I have a function that stores files data in an object. The files get saved in the object with their original names, I want to rename the files names with custom names.

That's what I did, it works fine, I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it without the mediation of a new variable(`newObj`).

```
const {
    'test123': purchase, 
    'test456': purchase2, 
    ...rest
} = stories
 newObj = {purchase, ...rest}
 console.log(newObj)
```

Stories object:

```
stories {
    'test123': StoryProvider {
              info: StoryInfo {
                client: [Object],
                company: [Object],
              },
              costs: StoryCosts {
                test: test,
              }
    },
    'test456': StoryProvider {
              info: StoryInfo {
                client: [Object],
                company: [Object],
              },
              costs: StoryCosts {
                test: test,
              }
     }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could break your problem down to just the part about renaming things. All of the code around importing the JSON file, the `XlsxPopulate`, `StoryProvider` and promises make that hard to identify and reproduce.

Comment: so you are renaming every object ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Supercool. Please see my edited question.

Comment: So, what would be nice is something simplified down to just the renaming part. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/tv902kj8/1/. I have no idea if that gets across what you're trying to do, because I'm still not sure what you're trying to rename to what.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Is now better?

Comment: @user3378165 why avoid creating a new object ? Is it the new object you want to avoid or the new variable ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, Right, I would actually want to avoid the extra variable `newObj`

Comment: @user3378165 closed it a duplicate. There are multiple answers there that fit the requirement. 3rd most voted offers single line rename as well.